# Cloudformation Export Outputs / Input parameters cross-account

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a parent cloudformation script that launches two child cloudformation scripts, each in separate accounts. Is there a way I can get outputs from one of the child stacks and use them as inputs in the other child stack, all done from this parent template? The user should be able to input different account numbers as a parameter as this script will be run across several different accounts.

Parent template sample code:

```
Resources:
  ChildAccountA:
    Type: Custom::StackA
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: example
      TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/exampleA
  ChildAccountB:
    Type: Custom::StackB
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: example
      TemplateURL: https://s3.amazonaws.com/exampleB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand, then yes. Your custom resource lambda should **return the outputs to the parent stack**.

The custom lambda obviously needs to have correct **permissions to be able to deploy stacks** in other accounts and get their outputs to be returned to the parent stack.

Since you haven't written if there are any issues with development of custom resources, I will just put the link to AWS [crhelper](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/custom-resource-helper). The helper simplify development of custom resources and returning results to it.

Just for completeness, for deployment of stacks in different regions and accounts, [StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html).